# React app white screen of death but status online withour error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, pm2

I am a freshers, after deploy a react app on server getting white screen of death, when status and out-log having no issue and no error log found. Can anybody help how to debug in this situation.

I am redeploy the app on a fresh server below latest out.log

```
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma | > sixam-mart@0.1.0 start
0|sixam-ma | > next start -p 3002
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma | > sixam-mart@0.1.0 start
0|sixam-ma | > next start -p 3002
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma | > sixam-mart@0.1.0 start
0|sixam-ma | > next start -p 3002
0|sixam-ma |
0|sixam-ma | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3002, url: http://localhost:3002
0|sixam-ma | info  - Loaded env from /home/..../public/.env.production
0|sixam-ma | { lanDirection: 'ltr' }
```

no error log found

```
────┬───────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name          │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ sixam-mart    │ default     │ 0.39.3  │ fork    │ 62363    │ 7m     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 58.6mb   │ ubuntu   │ disabled │
└────┴───────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────
```

below nginx reverse proxy settings

```
location / {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
proxy_redirect http://localhost:3002/ https://$server_name/;
}
```

Comment: What does your landing page code look like?

Comment: Open network tab and see if resources load

Comment: tnx @Konrad problem with nginx CROS issue. now solve.